# How to fix Unknown sources error during App install?

Tags: android, apk, android-install-apk

Created an App in android studio. While try to install it in real device. I am getting an error **"For Security, your phone is set to block installation of apps obtained from Unknown sources."**

I removed this error by going to setting and enabled install from Unknown sources. After that app get installed.

Question:
1) How can i  make this app as trusted known source for installation without making Unknown sources option enabled.

Even i tried to create a signed APK in android studio. But Still real device is reporting as Unknown sources.

Can someone help me to make App as trusted known source?

Comment: You will have to learn how to [sign your app](https://developer.android.com/studio/publish/app-signing)

Comment: You have to publish your app on Google Play Store

Comment: The only way is to publish your app on the play store.

Comment: Even i have signed app in android studio, But i am getting error in real device. Is it necessary to publish to play store for making it trusted known apk

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All apps outside of Google Play Store will get the Unknown Source Error.

**You must upload your apk file to your google play developer console and user must download your app via Google Play**. Otherwise user should enable the Unknown Sources checkbox from the settings in order to install the app.

When you sign your application, you will prevent from tampering the original source and when the attacker tampered your application and signed it with his key OS will alert the user to uninstall the app and install the fresh version to prevent data hijacking. But this still doesn't make the app as trusted app.

Hence all the apps, signed or unsigned, outside the Google Play Store are considered as app from unknown source.

Comment: Little correction @Koorosh, If app is signed by someone who does not have access to Signing keys, then he can not upload the tampered version to play store. Signing is also used for authenticating your ownership over the applications. It has nothing to do with validation and prompt for reinstalling the untampered version. Instead it shows the prompt even before the installation of the app with different signature.

Comment: that's what i've said